# center 3dpdf media display

Tags: 3d

I'm new in 3D pdf generation. I created a U3D file, than converted to 3D PDF with texworks(using movie 15 package). It's working, but a media display window is not centered, if a increase the size.
My tex file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,portrait, top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{article}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\includemovie[
    poster,
    toolbar, %same as `controls'
    label=koord.u3d,
        text=(Click here to see the 3D view),
    3Daac=60.000000, 3Droll=0.000000, 3Dc2c=0.996600 -38.220001 -1.019000, 3Droo=38.246571, 3Dcoo=0.996595 13.730411 1.019460,
    3Dlights=CAD,
]{20 cm }{16 cm}{koord.u3d}
\end{document}
```

I', looking forward to your answers. 
Thanks
Peter
[At the image you can see, tha media display window is not centered]

Comment: Hi, welcome. `movie15` is obsolete, try `media9` : https://ctan.org/pkg/media9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues.

1. In the log file one finds

   ```
   LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
       [portrait,top=1in,bottom=1.25in,left=1.25in,right=1.25in].
   ```

   Thus, the class options have no effect. Instead, use the `geometry` package to adjust the page set-up:

   ```latex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[a4paper,portrait, top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
   ```
2. However, these settings give you a line width of 416.83289 pt which is not enough for an object of 20 cm (= 569.05511 pt) width to be centred horizontally. It will produce an "overfull hbox" warning.

The 3D display area behaves like any other object that makes up a TeX box, such as an included graphic, a `tabular`, or a single letter. To centre these horizontally, use the `center` environment or the `\centering` command inside a `figure` or `table` environment. Of course, the width of the object may not exceed the available line width.

As stated in the comments, `movie15` is obsolete. Use `media9` instead. In the following code, the display area has dimensions of 10 cm by 10 cm, which result from the size of the poster argument. It is centred by means of the `center` environment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,portrait, top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \includemedia[
%    width=10cm,
%    height=10cm,
    3Dmenu, % various settings via mouse right-click
    3Dtoolbar,
    3Daac=60.000000, 3Droll=0.000000, 3Dc2c=0.996600 -38.220001 -1.019000, 3Droo=38.246571, 3Dcoo=0.996595 13.730411 1.019460,
    3Dlights=CAD
  ]{\vbox to 10cm{
    \vss
    \hbox to 10cm{\hss(Click here to see the 3D view)\hss}
    \vss
  }}{koord.u3d}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```